# R CMD build temp directory location

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

When executing `R CMD build <packagename>,` it each time creates a directory in the temp folder, including log files. If the build fails, I would like to look at this folder and the log files.

Is there a way to (parameter) execute `R CMD build` so that the temp directory's path is printed to the console?
Same problem when using devtools::build() or pkgbuild::pkgbuild(). They did return the path to the tar.gz when the build was successful, but they do not return anything if the build fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need are the log files, would the `--log` option be sufficient?

```sh
R CMD build --log pkgdir
```